# Z axis Stepper motors not working correctly

Tags: diy-3d-printer, reprap, ramps-1.4, z-axis

I have been searching around the internet for the last 3 days trying to figure this out. My Z axis motors for a pursa-i3 3d printer are not working correctly. I have marlin firmware and using repetier host. I send a command to move the z axis and I get it to move, however I if I send the same command again the motors will sometimes spin the other way. feel like They almost randomly choose which direction they turn.

As I said I have been trouble shooting this for a while now. What I am suspecting is the firmware feedrates and acceleration or some setting is not correct.

Here is my code:

```
//// MOVEMENT SETTINGS
#define NUM_AXIS 4 // The axis order in all axis related arrays is X, Y, Z, E
#define HOMING_FEEDRATE {50*60, 50*60, 2*60, 0}  // set the homing speeds (mm/min)

#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT   {80,80,4000,590}  
#define DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE          {300, 300, 3, 45}    // (mm/sec)
#define DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION      {1000,1000,50,500}    // X, Y, Z, E maximum start speed for accelerated moves. E default values are good for Skeinforge 40+, for older versions raise them a lot.

#define DEFAULT_ACCELERATION          1000    // X, Y, Z and E max acceleration in mm/s^2 for printing moves
#define DEFAULT_RETRACT_ACCELERATION  1000   // X, Y, Z and E max acceleration in mm/s^2 for retracts

#define DEFAULT_XYJERK                10   // (mm/sec)
#define DEFAULT_ZJERK                 0.3     // (mm/sec)
#define DEFAULT_EJERK                 5.0    // (mm/sec)
```

I tried swapping the drivers around and the motors will work perfectly on another axis so I don't suspect it to be a driver issue. I have been turning the pots ontop of the drivers to make them work but can't make them to go the same direction i want them to.

I've checked the wires and I almost sure they are wired up correctly. (could be wrong but have checked it over with a multimeter.)

I am new to this and it's my first time building one of these would appreciate any help I can get and and maybe I have over looked something I have tested.
Just really want the axis to move in the direction That I say it to move in.

---

More details about my setup is: A Robocraze 3D Printer Controller Board RAMPS 1.4 using A4988 stepper motors drivers and my motors are the nema 17 stepper motors. I currently have the two z axis motors wired in parallel but have tried before using series, however the problem of being unable to control the direction of the Z motors still arises (can easily switch back to series).

currently trying with no load just to get the motors turn in the correct direction when I send a G-code command. I am using Repetier host on ubuntu 14.04.5.

I have also check the endstops and they are working perfectly, so they ain't a problem (I don't think :p)

Thank you,
Bobby

Comment: Not sure if I asked a clear enough question, hoping for some help and can provide more details if needed?

Comment: Try adding more specifics on your wiring, the servos you use, etc. There is something not completely obvious going on here.

Comment: Added a few more details and yeah I can understand :(, hoping someone has faced the same issue?  really odd because when I send the exact same g-code command repeatedly The Z axis will turn back and forth clockwise then Anti clockwise with each different command! Such a headache hahaha, Thank you

Comment: Did you try with just one of the motors connected? What if you disconnect the motor coupling? You need to isolate electronic/software and mechanical issues as the potential cause.

Comment: Hello, Yes I have tried with just one motor connected to the Z driver and still same issue, even different motors completely. I know it is something that is wrong with the Z pins, driver or firmware (feed rates as such are different). I have tried swapping the drivers and it works in other slots for the x,y or extruder motors, so i don't think the driver is the problem. Could be maybe the RAMPS board slot for the Z motors is faulty? I am guessing that since no one has jumped up and said anything about the code, the firmware is fine? so it must be the RAMPS board Z driver socket???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after 5 days of trouble shooting, Bob-the-Kuhn over on the marlin github forum solved it for, anyone else who faces the same issue can head over to github for my solutions.

https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/9287#issuecomment-359428147

Conversation from link:

> **Bob-the-Kun:**
> Problem does not follow the driver. Problem does not follow the
> steppers.
>
> I'm thinking that the Z socket has a problem. Sounds like an open/poor
> contact.
>
> Try bending the DIRECTION lead on the Z driver a little and see if the
> problem disappears. It's one of the corner pins. Sometimes it's called
> DIR. If your driver's pins aren't labeled then bend all four corner
> pins a little.
>
> Another option is to move the Z function to the E1 socket. Replace
> your pins_RAMPS.h file with this one. pins_RAMPS.zip
>
> FYI - if this really is a hardware problem then it's the second RAMPS
> hardware problem within a week. Most unusual.
>
> **Post reply:**
>
> Yes the socket I am now assuming is just broken (not sure what exactly
> but possibly one of the connections), After using for pins_RAMPS file
> and changed the motors back to series and connected to the E1 slot I
> successful got the printer to work!!! Thank you very much Z axis is
> working as I would expect! I am now calibrating the printer as it
> definitely needs it.

Comment: It's great that you took the time to come back and share that you solved the problem.  It's sub-optimal - though - that you just put a link.  Stuff changes / get moved / is deleted from the internet, and the risk is the link will break at some point in the future.  It would be great if you could al least add a summary of what the solution is all about. :)